# regex for a pattern, but also negate a word

Tags: regex, regex-negation

Is there a regex for not including a given word, but matching another pattern?

I have a simple pattern like the following for grabbing words in a parser I'm using.

```
field = re.compile(r"[a-zA-Z0-9]+")
```

It works fine for the parser to determine whether something is a variable or function, but I'm running into an issue where it grabs the closing code blocks, which use the **end** keyword.

```
    foo = 3
end if <-- end is a keyword and should not be counted as a variable
```

Is there a way to update the regex to match all the words it currently matches except for the word **end**?

**foo** would be a match.

**en** would be a match.

**end** would *not* be a match.

**endx** would be a match.

Comment: How about `\b(?!end\b)[a-zA-Z0-9]+`?

Comment: That looks like it does what I need.  Thanks!  I'll have to read up on \b.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the comments @phylogenesis provided a working answer

```
\b(?!end\b)[a-zA-Z0-9]+
```

I'll explain why/how this regex answers your question.

The key is the [negative lookahead](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) `(?!end\b)` with the [word boundaries](https://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html) `\b` performing a crucial supporting role.

The leading `\b` ensures that your pattern matches from the beginning of a word, then the negative lookahead `(?!end\b)` only allows the pattern to match if the first three letters of the word are not e,n,d followed by a word boundary (a.k.a. the word 'end'). The word boundary in this lookahead makes sure that it doesn't weed out words like 'endive'.